# how to pass a generic type parameter in method

Tags: c#, database, generics, reflection

**I have a generic class and have some method**.
The methods work is **Insert, update ,delete** in database using reflection.
**But my problem is I cannot insert pass values in Insert Method**

that's the main class when I called my insert method, I can not pass values

**MyORM** class

```
public class MyORM<T> where T:IData
{
    private SqlConnection _sqlConnection;

    public MyORM(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
    {
        _sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    }

    public MyORM(string connectionString)
        : this(new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

    }

    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        var sql = new StringBuilder("insert into ");
        var type = item.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        sql.Append(type.Name);
        sql.Append("( ");

        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            sql.Append(property.Name);
            sql.Append(",");
        }

        sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1, 1);

        sql.Append(" ) values (");

        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            sql.Append("@");
            sql.Append(property.Name);
            sql.Append(",");
        }
        sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1, 1);
        sql.Append(");");

        var query = sql.ToString();

        var command = new SqlCommand(query,_sqlConnection);

        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(property.GetValue(item));
        }


    }
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var orm = new MyORM<StudentInfo>(DbConnection.connectionString);
        orm.Insert();
}
```

Comment: This isn't what generics are meant to be used for... also, why not just use EF instead?

Comment: You don't know how to pass a parameter of type T or you don't know how to access these parameters inside Insert Method?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Int32 objects.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(Object value)
   at Assignment.MyORM`1.Insert(T item) in D:\DevSkill\dotNet\Code\Asp.NetBatch5\AspDotNetMVC\Assignment\Assignment_2\Assignment\MyORM.cs:line 68
FInish

Answer (score 0):

**There are a number of issues with your existing code:**

- For this to work as intended, you need to pass parameter names *and* values

```cs
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + property.Name, property.GetValue(item));
}
```

- You also need to actually execute the `SqlCommand`

```cs
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

- I recommend that you find a way to specify the exact parameter types and lengths, perhaps via an attribute, rather than using `AddWithValue`
- I also *strongly* recommend you do *not* cache the connection object, and instead create it when needed in a `using` block

Comment: the exact problem, I do not understand exactly how to pass value.

Comment: Have I not given you that in the first code block?